# sfml проблема с правами доступа при чтении

Tags: c++, библиотеки, sfml

Проблема видна на скрине. Все библиотеки подключены правильно. После пары компиляций начала появляться ошибка. 
[image: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу (SFML sfml-system-d-2.dll)]

Comment: Может библиотека sfml собрана другой версией компилятора?

Comment: Весь код показывайте.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. В проекте были файлы библиотеки версии 2.2 а я использовал версию 2.4

Comment: "Все библиотеки подключены правильно."

Comment: @Croessmah Но после пары компиляций это изменилось, оно всегда так.

Comment: они подключены правильно, но те что были подключены, и те что были в папке отличались.